# Improve Quality of JPGraph Charts for printing

Tags: php, image, charts, png, jpgraph

I generate PNG Charts with JPGraph. It works ok, but I have the problem, that the quality of the pictures is very poor when printing it. It is very grainy. I read the docs, but I did not find anything how to improve the image quality of the charts. Especially the labels and the

I tried to create the charts with a higher width and height, but this does not work, because the gaps between the ticks get bigger.

Do you have any ideas how to create "print ready" charts with jpGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ideally need to be creating vector graphics if you want to produce something that can be scaled up and will print nicely.

Take a look at [this](http://devzone.zend.com/1683/creating-scalable-vector-graphs-with-php/), it is the best thing I can find in the first few results on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+vector+graphics) (which, by the way, will be your friend, if your nice to it...)

Comment: I accepted the answer because of the hint with the vector graphics. What I do not like about this answer is, that you are implying, that I did not search for solutions by my own with google. This is not fair and absolutely not correct. Nevertheless, thanks for your hint!

Comment: @DominikObermaier I apologise for implying that you had been lazy in your researh, but I will say that you need to work on *what* to search for when using Google. Since what you are basically doing is wanting to produce and *image* and *scale* it up, if you search for ["scalable image"](http://www.google.com/search?q=scalable+image) the first result is a Wikipedia article about vector graphics. I am so used to seeing questions where the OP has done little or no research that it is something of a gut reaction and I didn't mean to offend.